# Boot Camp Brightness meter has no effect in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, display, boot-camp, brightness

I upgraded to Windows 8, and now I can't change the screen brightness. The F1/F2 keys do alter the brightness meter in the Boot Camp Control Panel, but this level has no effect on the actual brightness of the screen.

Comment: Please reopen this. It's quite clear that I want a fix for my laptop's brighness buttons to work again.

Comment: can't reopen but the latest BootCamp drivers for 8.1 have fixed this issue on one of my setups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a BootCamp driver issue, you will have to wait until Apple updates their BootCamp drivers to support Windows 8.

Comment: @mcandre instead of editing the answer, you should use comments to respond if the answer works or not.